# Insert a new line after a matching pattern

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file with patterns like

```
abc.example.com def.example.com xyz.example.com
```

I want the output to be in next line after every `example.com` like:

```
abc.example.com
def.example.com
xyz.example.com
```

I tried `grep -oP'(example.com$)'` and `grep -oP'*.(example.com$)` but I am not getting the desired result. With the first one I am getting only `example.com` as result and each result is in new line. With second one I am getting error `quantifier does not follow a repeatable pattern`

Comment: I edited your question for clarity as what you have actually presented is one blank line after every line containing the string example.com. If the three strings in your expected output were on consecutive lines, then that would still be a new line after every such occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed -E 's/(\S+example\.com) /\1\n/g' file
abc.example.com
def.example.com
xyz.example.com
```

Or taking advantage of *word-spliting* :

```
printf '%s\n' $(< file)
```

(in the case you don't care about matching `example.com`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want to replace spaces with newlines, you may do so with `tr`:

```bash
$ tr ' ' '\n' <file
abc.example.com
def.example.com
xyz.example.com
```

Or, with `sed`:

```bash
$ sed -e 'y/ /\n/' file
abc.example.com
def.example.com
xyz.example.com
```

---

Regarding your attempts:

- The first one, `grep -oP'(example.com$)'` (which lacks a space between the `-P` option and the actual expression, and which could be simplified into `grep -o 'example.com$'`), asks to extract the text that matches `example.com` at the end of a line.  This is what it does.
- The second one, `grep -oP'*.(example.com$)` (which, like the first, lacks a space between the `-P` option and the expression, and additionally lacks a closing single quote, and which could probably be simplified into `grep -o -P '*.example.com$'`), tries to use the `*` modifier at the start of the expression.  This is *legal* in a *basic* regular expression (which is what `grep` uses by default, without `-P` or `-E`), and such a `*` would match a literal asterisk character.  This is not allowed in a PCRE (or extended regular expression).  GNU `grep`, therefore, correctly complains about this.

What I think that you possibly attempted to do was

```bash
$ grep -o '[^ ]*\.example\.com\>' file
abc.example.com
def.example.com
xyz.example.com
```

This uses the non-standard (but commonly implemented) `-o` option to extract each substring that starts with some non-space characters followed by the literal string `.example.com`, where the final `m` ends a "word".

Comment: OP asked after example.com, not very clear if he need to match those patterns or not. I assumed yes

Comment: @GillesQuenot So they did, but they are only showing data where it's the spaces that actually matter for the end result, not the rest of the data.  If they add information that invalidates this answer, I will naturally modify or delete it.